# (KivyMD) How to change the text of an MDLabel?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Here is my code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

n = 1

class Screen1(Screen):
    pass

class Screen2(Screen):
    def set_number(self, n):
        self.ids["number"].text == f"{n}"
        print(f"The n variabile value is: {n}")
        txt = self.ids["number"].text
        print(f"The displayed number is: {txt}\n")
        return
    
    

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Screen1(name="Screen1"))
sm.add_widget(Screen2(name="Screen2"))


class TestApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
       self.title = "Test app"
       self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Indigo"
       self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "600"
       screen =  Builder.load_file("test.kv")
       return screen



    def arrow_up(self):
        global n
        if n == 5:
            pass
        else:
            n += 1
            Screen2().set_number(n)
        
    def arrow_down(self):
        global n
        if n == 1:
            pass
        else:
            n -= 1
            Screen2().set_number(n)
        





if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

And here my KV file:

```
ScreenManager:
    id: scrn_mngr
    Screen1:
    Screen2:


<Screen1>:
    id: Scrn1    
    name: "Screen1"
    MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
        text: "Next screen"
        icon: "arrow-right"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        width: dp(180)
        on_press: root.manager.current = "Screen2" 



<Screen2>
    id: Scrn2 
    name: "Screen2"    
    MDFloatingActionButton:
        icon: "arrow-up-bold-outline"
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .4, "center_y": .5}
        on_press: app.arrow_up()
    MDFloatingActionButton:
        icon: "arrow-down-bold-outline"
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .6, "center_y": .5}
        on_press: app.arrow_down()    
    MDLabel:
        text: "Number"
        halign: "center"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .55}
    MDLabel:
        id: number
        text: "1"
        halign: "center"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
```

I'm trying to increase and decrease the variable n using the two MDFloatingActionButton on the second screen. The problem is that the text property of the MDLabel does not change as n increase or decrease, and always display the number one, even if n actually change correctly.
I can't figure out what's wrong, can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines:

```
Screen2().set_number(n)
```

will have no effect on your GUI. When you use `Screen2()` you are creating a new instance of `Screen2` which has no relation to the one displayed in your GUI. So calling `Screen2().set_number(n)` is setting `n` in an instance of `Screen2` that is not displayed in your GUI.

There are several ways to fix this. One way is to just move the `arrow_up()` and `arrow_down()` methods into the `Screen2` class like this:

```
class Screen2(Screen):
    def set_number(self, n):
        self.ids["number"].text = f"{n}"  # Note: changed == to =
        print(f"The n variabile value is: {n}")
        txt = self.ids["number"].text
        print(f"The displayed number is: {txt}\n")
        return

    def arrow_up(self):
        global n
        if n == 5:
            pass
        else:
            n += 1
            self.set_number(n)

    def arrow_down(self):
        global n
        if n == 1:
            pass
        else:
            n -= 1
            self.set_number(n)
```

Then in the 'kv' change `app.arrow_down()` and `app.arrow_up()` to refer to `root` instead of `app`:

```
<Screen2>
    id: Scrn2 
    name: "Screen2"    
    MDFloatingActionButton:
        icon: "arrow-up-bold-outline"
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .4, "center_y": .5}
        on_press: root.arrow_up()
    MDFloatingActionButton:
        icon: "arrow-down-bold-outline"
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .6, "center_y": .5}
        on_press: root.arrow_down()    
    MDLabel:
        text: "Number"
        halign: "center"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .55}
    MDLabel:
        id: number
        text: "1"
        halign: "center"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
```